# How to use a variable inside $('#id option:eq(VARIABLE)')?

Tags: jquery

I basically want to set some dropdown menu to a certain index by comparing to the respective value.
Here's the code:

```js
function InitializeLieblingsplatzOptions(){
  $.post('../include/retrieveLieblingsplatz.php',{
  //nothing to transmit
  }).then((data) => {
    data = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log("data in retrieveLieblingsplatz.php is ", data)

    //let test = $('#liebraum').find("test")
    $('#liebraum option:eq(data.raum)').prop('selected', true)
    $('#liebsitz option:eq(data.nummer)').prop('selected', true)



  })
}
```

the data returned from the ajax contains two strings which represent a roomname and seatnumber. There are 2 dropdown menus on this site which contain all names of all rooms and all available seats of the respective room.
I now want to use the 2 strings returned by the AJAX to set the options of these dropdown menus to the respective options. Therefore I'm using these two jquery commands already displayed above:

```js
$('#liebraum option:eq(data.raum)').prop('selected', true)
$('#liebsitz option:eq(data.nummer)').prop('selected', true)
```

Currently, nothing is happening ^^ Its like the two dropwdown menus are not even touched. I wonder if this is because I have to put these variables containing the strings to compare to into the " '' " clause. Because of this they are just regarded as strings, not as variables. I never had such a case so far in the context of jquery and I have no idea if there is a way to deal with it Oo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using the css selector like so

```
$('#liebraum option:eq('+data.raum+')').prop('selected', true);
```

or by using the .eq method exposed by jQuery.

```
$('#liebraum option').eq(data.raum).prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please search how to concatenate strings in javascript...

```
$('#yourID option:eq(' + yourVariable + ')')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 template literals:

```
$(`#liebraum option:eq(${data.raum})`)
```

Or, if you want to stick to ES5, use `String` concatenation:

```
$('#liebraum option:eq('+data.raum+')')
```